# VBA merging entries of arrays of different dimesion

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, merge

I would like to merge the entries of two arrays and save the mergings in a new array.

For example:

```
array1 = ("Name1", "Name2")
array2 = ("top","tip","tap")
```

The result should look like this:

```
array3 = ("Name1top","Name1tip","Name1tap","Name2top","Name2tip","Name3tap")
```

I tried using for-slopes, but I somehow didn't manage to get the result I was looking for.

Comment: Always helps to show the code you tried and mention how it didn't meet your needs

Answer (score 0):

frank, one way to do it is to nest 2 loops (slopes ??)

```
'Create the two files starting at index 0
array1 = Split("Name1,Name2", ",")
array2 = Split("top,tip,tap", ",")

'get the length of the arrays
len1 = UBound(array1) - LBound(array1) + 1 
len2 = UBound(array2) - LBound(array2) + 1

'Create an array which holds all combinations. There are len1*len2 times of these
ReDim array3(0 To len1 * len2 - 1)

'Build all combinations with 2 nested loops
For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
    For k = LBound(array2) To UBound(array2)
        array3(i * len1 + k) = array1(i) & array2(k) 'the index of array3 is a bit tricky, take a bit of time why it is constructed this way
    Next k
Next i
```

Comment: Yes, we had the same assignment.

Comment: how array1 and array2 accesed with index 1 it should be 0.